# Limitations of optimisation software such as CPLEX

Tags: optimization, cplex

Which of the following optimisation methods can't be done in an optimisation software such as CPLEX? Why not?

- Dynamic programming
- Integer programming
- Combinatorial optimisation
- Nonlinear programming
- Graph theory
- Precedence diagram method
- Simulation
- Queueing theory

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I didn't find too much information regarding the limitations of CPLEX on the IBM website.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's kind-of a big shopping list, and most of the things on it are not optimisation methods.

For sure CPLEX does integer programming, non-linear programming (just quadratic, SOCP, and similar but not general non-linear) and combinatoric optimisation out of the box.

It is usually possible to re-cast things like DP as MILP models, but will obviously require a bit of work. Lots of MILP models are also based on graphs, so yes it is certainly possible to solve a lot of graph problems using a MILP solver such as CPLEX.

Looking wider at topics like simulation, then that is quite a different approach. Simulation really is NOT an optimisation method, but it can be used alongside optimisation to get extra insights which may be useful in a business context. Might be used for example to discover some empirical relationships that could be used in an optimisation model by CPLEX.

The same can probably also be said for things like queuing theory, precedence, etc. Basically, use CPLEX as an optimisation tool to solve part or all of your problem once you have structured and analysed it via one of these other approaches.

Hope that helps.